# Unterminated string literal in javascript code and am not sure about PHP code either

Tags: javascript, php

[image]I have an error in the following code which says UNTERMINATED STRING LITERAL please help me and also tell me php code is on right place because it is before script tag so how can can be isset true?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if(isset($_REQUEST['page']))
                {
                    $page=$_REQUEST['page'];
                }
        ?>
        <form action="yea.php" method="post">
            <select name="page" onchange="hitme('<?php echo $page;?>');">
                <option value="home">home</option>
                <option value="about">about</option>
                <option value="menu">menu</option>
                <option value="download">download</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <script>
            function hitme(page)
                {
                    switch(page)
                        {
                            case "home":
                            document.write("you selected home");
                            break;

                            case "menu":
                            document.write("you selected menu");
                            break;

                            case "about":
                            document.write("you selected about");
                            break;

                            default:
                            document.write("invalid selection!");
                        }
                }

                document.write("<br>it will print no matter what!");
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your code is okay, there should be not such error with posted code.

Comment: since $page is not defined its giving PHP ERROR which getting passed to script as `hitme('<br /> <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: page in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\demo_places2\phpdemo2.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br /> ');` check my answer

Answer (score 1):

i have question as you mentioned in comment why u need php to do that

```
        <form action="yea.php" method="post">
            <select name="page" onchange="hitme(this);">
                <option value="home">home</option>
                <option value="about">about</option>
                <option value="menu">menu</option>
                <option value="download">download</option>
            </select>

            <span id="pagename"></span>
        </form>
        <script>
            function hitme(page)
                {
                    switch(page.value)
                        {
                            case "home":
                            document.getElementById("pagename").innerHTML = "you selected home";
                            break;

                            case "menu":
                           document.getElementById("pagename").innerHTML = "you selected menu";
                            break;

                            case "about":
                             document.getElementById("pagename").innerHTML = "you selected about";

                            break;

                            default:
                             document.getElementById("pagename").innerHTML = "invalid selection!";

                        }
                }

                alert("<br>it will print no matter what!");
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: well it is working thanks.....but what if someone wants to do it using php for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

change your php code as

```
<?php


            if(isset($_REQUEST['page']))
                {
                    $page=$_REQUEST['page'];
                }
                else
                $page="";
        ?>
```

Comment: okay i changed my code but now on selecting any option it always showing invalid selection which is default block of switch.

Comment: i want whenever i select any option from drop down list it will show message according to my selection. like if i  select menu it should show me you selected menu...

Answer (score 0):

in PHP if block you use logal $page you need use global. So you must declare a $page variable higher of if block.